# ManyToOne annotation for long attribute jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

i have a class that contains a foreign key for another class in JPA ,  i want Long id to be a foreign key instead of full object , is that possible ?

```
public class Site extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    private double longitude;

    @NotNull
    private double latitude;

    public Site() {
    }
}

public class NetworkElement extends AbstractEntity {


    private NetworkElementType networkElementType;


    @ManyToOne 
    private Site site;

    public NetworkElement(){
    }

}
```

i need to put instead of Site Site, Long idSite
is that possible ?
thank you

Comment: Format your question carefully.

Comment: i just want to replace Site Site with Long idSite, thats all

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? You can at any time just get that id with `getSite().getId()`